# Does Magic Lantern support the Canon 80D?

Tags: canon, magic-lantern, camera

It seems that Magic Lantern has several features that is very handy for a photographer, i.e. Focus Peaking and Zebra (which Canon sadly left out in its latest mid-range DSLR) but after searching for compatibility online, I couldn't find any result.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I've retitled the older question to remove the model specificity, since basically it's for all Canon cameras that are too new to have an ML build. It's now called: "Is there a way to get Magic Lantern on my newer model Canon dSLR?"  Unless someone else edits it. :)

Comment: As usual I always wonder why people ask general forums instead of the forum on the, in this case, Magic Lantern website where you'd get a definitive answer.

Comment: The problem is the website isn't as reliable as sometimes the pages load (awfully) slow, especially the forums, most often not even loading at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://builds.magiclantern.fm/ this is the list of supported models and at present 80D is not there.